# Exclude Admin profiles from Apex Class

Tags: apex, profile

In no way am I a developer, but our SalesForce developer quit so I (an admin) have to add this functionality.

Before the developer quit, he created an Export Compliance page, so when the user clicks on an opportunity it will take them to an APEX page and ask the user questions and the user will answer yes or no if the opportunity complies. What I'm wanting to do is have the administrator profiles be excluded from this Export Compliance. I imagine I would have some kind of 'If statement' that looks a the system administrator profile?

Also, there are 3 apex classes that has to do with Export Compliance. ExportCheckApproval, ExportCheckMasterHandler, ExportCheckPageController so I'm not really sure where I should add the code either.

Here's the code from ExportCheckPageController:

```
 PageReference pr1;

        if(opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT){
        if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null){
            pr1 = new PageReference('/apex/ExportCheckPage1?oppId='+ opp.Id);
            pr1.setRedirect(true); 
        }
    }
    else{
        pr1 = new PageReference('/' + opp.id);
        pr1.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    }
    return pr1;





 PageReference pr;

    if((UserInfo.getuserId() == opp.ownerid) &&
        (opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT)){
            //if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null){
                    pr = new PageReference('/apex/ExportCheckPage1?oppId='+ opp.Id);
                    pr.setRedirect(true); 
            //}
            }
    else{
    pr = new PageReference('/' + opp.id);
    pr.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
        }

    return pr;
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi Matt and welcome to SFSE. One way you could do this would be to query for profiles where the name is not equal to "Administrator". The 3 classes you've told us are custom (meaning your Dev wrote them), so we'd at least need to know what was in them to help.

Personally though, I'd advise your employer you're not a developer and simply aren't trained in this particular skillset. At least, that's what it sounds like!

Comment: Hi Poet, thank you for your reply. I realize I'm not trained for this skill set but have some coding experience so I thought I'd try and tackle the issue. I can read code decently and understand most of it, but syntax kills me. I've update the post if you would like to look at the Controller's code where I think you would handle all the queries for the user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a action method define in your visualforce page which call your redirect method which check and redirect for compliance page so put following code inside your redirect method

```
public PageReference redirect(){
//*************get the sys admin id***************
Id SYS_ADMIN_PROFILE_ID = [select ProfileId 
             from User 
             where Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'].ProfileId
    PageReference pr;
    if((UserInfo.getProfileId() != SYS_ADMIN_PROFILE_ID) &&
    (opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT)){
        if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null){
            pr = new PageReference('/apex/ExportCheckPage1?oppId='+ opp.Id);
            pr.setRedirect(true); 
        }
    }
    else{
        pr = new PageReference('/' + opp.id);
        pr.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    }
    return pr;
}
```

if you have multiple system administrator custom profile.

```
String Profilename = [select Name from profile where id=:UserInfo.getProfileId()]

if(!Profilename.tolowercase().contains('admin') &&
    (opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT)
```

if you have opportunity owner

```
if(UserInfo.getuserId()== opp.ownerid &&
    (opp.RecordTypeId == sgiRT || opp.RecordTypeId == apacRT)
```

Comment: Those Admin profiles could be custom profiles and there could be several of them depending on the size of the org. So, he may need to query for multiple profile names which will return a list of Ids. He'll then need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: yes I agree. I have only given the start point to him with best case scenario. @crmprogdev

Comment: thank y'all so much. I assume I would just add the custom system admin profiles by adding 'or' statements?

Comment: check the updated answer. @Matt

Comment: @Himanshu sorry to keep changing the requirements but when I got the code working my boss changes the requirements :( It's of going off profile name he just wants users that are 'opportunity owners' to see the compliance page. how would I go about that?

Comment: in that case you can compare opp.ownerid == userinfo.getuserid() as shown in updated answer

Comment: @Himanshu I cleared up some errors and now I get this error:SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.OwnerId
Error is in expression '{!redirect}' in component <apex:page> in page standardopportunity: Class.ExportCheckPageController.redirect: line 89, column 1      I assume I need to query to get the owner id?

Comment: you need to add this field in your soql query. so update [Select Id, Name with Select Id, ownerid,Name

Comment: You are so awesome!!! @Himanshu I owe you a drink my friend. Cheers!

Comment: all pleasure is mine ;)

Comment: Hi @Himanshu I updated my post with the code you generously provided, and it's not validating that I am the opportunity owner because it's not showing the visual force page at all. If I'm the owner it's taking me straight to the opportunity and not to the compliance page. Can you please advise what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: have you removed sys admin logic ?

Comment: as you are system admin it is following that logic. Remove that admin logic and you will be redirected to compliance page

Comment: @Himanshu my code doesn't work anymore. Your functionality about if the userid and owner id matches does but the code that I had previously doesn't work. It just refreshes the compliance page and doesn't go to the opportunity if it doesn't have any compliance issues. I edited my code above. The 1st pageReference is what I originally had and the second page reference is what I have now. The way I got your code to work was commenting out this line: //if(!opp.isExportCompleted__c && exportCheck.Id == null), but I need that line of code and functionality. Do I need to do a if then else statement?